# Adjust picture width and height

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am trying to insert a picture and size it according to the cell's width and height and place it on the cell.

This is the subroutine

```
Sub insertPictures(vPath, cellAddress)

Dim img As Picture, r As Range

Set img = IREP.Pictures.Insert(vPath)
Set r = IREP.Range(cellAddress)

With img
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Top = r.Top
    .Left = r.Left
    .Width = r.Width
    .Height = r.Height
End With

End Sub
```

It inserts the picture where it should be but doesn't adjust the height or width as you can see in the screenshot below when I do

`Call PForm.insertPictures("C:\Users\vksk0\Pictures\Screenshots\Screen.png", "frontPic")`

to test the subroutine.

[image]

Comment: What is `IREP`?

Comment: @dwirony codename of the worksheet as you can see in the screenshot in the project workspace window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to position the image over a merged range, so try

```
.Width = r.MergeArea.Width
.Height = r.MergeArea.Height
```